# Use Environments with Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Can Azure Release Pipelines use the Environment feature?
I have been looking but all examples of using Environments are YAML and pipeline Deployment tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Environments are designed for multi stage Yaml pipelines. For release pipelines you have `Deployment groups`. Please check it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/deployment-groups-vs-environments/901600) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, from the answers I've got I believe I should be choosing YAML pipelines over classic and release pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Azure Release Pipelines use the Environment feature?

The answer is No, the environment feature cannot be used in the release pipeline. This is stated in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-get-started?view=azure-devops#feature-availability):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hugh, thats a useful document. I accepted the answer above as I got it first.